# Connect 2 ros board

Tags: robotic-arm, wifi, master, topics, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have 2 arm boards running ros. I need to share the topics between the boards.
I want to use a wired connection, is the uart a good choice? (I've got also lan or usb on both boards)
Is it possibile to do something like I do in wireless mode with the definition of master uri?
Maybe do I need to use rosserial?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250185/connect-2-ros-board/) by [RoboDroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/28822/robodroid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on your hardware, serial is typically 115.2kbps to 1Mbps, and Ethernet is typically 100Mbps to 1Gbps (100x faster), so Ethernet is generally the faster and more flexible solution.

Since you'll be setting up a point-to-point ethernet link, you'll probably need to assign static IP addresses to both boards. This is well-documented for most linux distributions and is outside the scope of this forum.

Setting up ROS to communicate over a network is usually as simple as following http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RoboDroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/28822/robodroid/) on 2016-12-16**:
Thanks, I'll try it.
But in the case I can't use ethernet, how can I use uart?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-16**:
I'm not certain it's possible to use the existing rosserial nodes over a point-to-point serial link, but you could probably use rosserial_python or rosserial_server on one end and write a custom node on the other end that uses the rosserial_embeddedlinux client.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-16**:
Really, I think using the serial link is such a poor idea that I don't want to give too many details. Using ROS over ethernet works, and that's where you should focus your energy.